# MLE of $\theta$ where the Likelihood function has a bunch of indicators

Tags: maximum-likelihood

> Suppose that two observations $X_1$ and $X_{2}$ are drawn at random from a distribution with the following probability density function
> $f_{\theta}(x)=\frac{1}{2\theta}$ if $0 ≤ x ≤ \theta$ or $2\theta ≤ x ≤ 3\theta$, otherwise, $f_{\theta}(x)= 0$ where $\theta > 0$ Determine the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ for each of the following observed values of $X_{1}$ and $X_2$.

(a) $X_{1}$ = 7 and $X_{2} = 9$

(b) $X_{1}$ = 4 and $X_{2} = 9$ .

(c) $X_{1}$ = 5 and $X_{2} = 9 $.

Note that $L(\theta)$ is a decreasing function of $\theta$, so the minimum value of $\theta$ that is admissible maximizes the likelihood function.
For (a) $L( \theta=3 | X_1, X_2)=\frac{1}{36}$. For any other theta $\geq 9$, we get $L<\frac{1}{324}$, otherwise $L=0$

For (b)  $L( \theta=4| X_1, X_2)=\frac{1}{64}$. For any other theta $\geq 9$, we get $L<\frac{1}{324}$ Otherwise, $L=0$

For (c)  $L( \theta=9| X_1, X_2)=\frac{1}{324}$. For any other theta $> 9$, we get $L<\frac{1}{324}$ Otherwise, $L=0$

Can someone please check if this is okay? Also not sure how to rigorously present the likelihood function.

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution is right. But I guess there is no need to calculate the value of likelihood. As you mentioned: $L(\theta)$ is a decreasing function of $\theta$, so we only need to find minimum admissible $\theta$. I prefer drawing the admissible $\theta$ in a number line for every $x_i$. First take the union, then take the intersection. Then you can find the minimum $\theta$. But if the sample size $n$ is large, this method is not feasible.

Comment: Union and intersection of?

Comment: For every $x_i$, the admissible $\theta$ is a union of two intervals, like (a) $x_1: A_1 = [7/3,7/2]\cup[7,\infty)$, and $x_2: A_2 = [9/3,9/2]\cup[9,\infty)$. Then $\hat{\theta}_\text{MLE}=\inf A_1 \cap A_2 = 3$.